# Flutter: Visual studio emulator

Tags: docker, android-emulator, flutter, visual-studio-emulator

Since I have Docker running, I read this guide: https://medium.com/@randombites/running-android-emulator-and-docker-simultaneously-on-windows-df570cfe3fd1
in order to run emulators. Now, if I run a normal Android project (from Android studio) on Visual studio emulator, as suggested by the guide, everything is fine, but, if I try to run a Flutter project, it gives me different errors like "an openGL error has occurred failed to read remote PID" or doesn´t start at all, throwing a timeout error.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

My last output:

Launching lib\main.dart on 5 inch KitKat 4 4 XXHDPI Phone in debug mode...

Initializing gradle...

Resolving dependencies...

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.

WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

timeout waiting for the application to start
Application finished.

Answer (score 0):

Running with software rendering might help

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

Comment: It gives me a warning:  linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix

Comment: Please add the full output to your question.

Comment: flutter run --enable-software-rendering

Launching lib/main.dart on 5 inch KitKat 4 4 XXHDPI Phone in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.1s
Resolving dependencies...                                    2.2s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                          3.4s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

Comment: Does the app run? You didn't mention the OpenGL error.

Comment: In this case it doesn´t throw the OpenGL error, but the app doesn´t start and in the console is dysplayed what I wrote...

Comment: I´ve just tried with a different emulator, 5 5 inch Marshmallow 6 0 0 XXHDPI Phone, and now throws out: an openGl error has occurred: Failed to read remote PID! The emulator will now shut down

Comment: With or without software-rendering?

Comment: without, I just start the simulator and run the app